# What do the arms mean on Shiva with six arms?

Tags: shiva

In St. Louis years ago I ran across a large statue (at least 26" across) of Shiva Nata-raja dancing within the circle of fire and the regular four arms. But this one had six distinct arms. It was not a modern variation but an old sculpture. Can anyone tell me about it, the meaning of the two additional arms? Thank you.